# Trouble in parsing date using dateutil

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-dateutil

I am using python-dateutil for parsing a date from a string:

```
import dateutil.parser
print dateutil.parser.parse('some null string', fuzzy=True).date()
2012-10-18
print dateutil.parser.parse('some 31 Oct 2012 string', fuzzy=True).date()
2012-10-31
```

What I am expecting is for `dateutil.parser.parse('some null string', fuzzy=True).date()` to throw an exception, but it's returning the current date. Can someone show me how I can avoid getting the current date, if no date is found in the provided string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you turn on `fuzzy`, you'll never get an exception...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See the [dateutil docs](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2), specifically the parse function (emphasizes mine):

> Additionally, the following keyword arguments are available:
>
> **default**
>   If given, this must be a datetime instance. Any fields missing in the parsed date will be copied from this instance. *The default value is the current date, at 00:00:00am*.
>
> ... (snip) ...
>
> **fuzzy**
>   If fuzzy is set to True, unknown tokens in the string will be ignored.

Given that you've set `fuzzy` to `True`, no exception will be thrown as it will simply ignore all unknown tokens. And, as the `default` argument is not passed, the current date will be returned.

So the solution will be to either keep `fuzzy` set to `False`, so that invalid format strings will throw an exception; or check if the returned datetime is equal to the current date at 00:00:00am as an indication of a failed conversion.

Comment: This is no longer true, as of v.2.5.0. If no date is found, even when fuzzy-parsing, `ValueError` will be raised.