# Extract YYYY-mm-dd dates from long text

Tags: python, regex, datetime

I have a html document with many lines like:

```
<option value="29">Soil Temperature (<i>2002-10-17</i>)</option>
```

or like:

```
<option value="STO">Soil &amp; Air Temperature (2002-10-17)</option>
```

For each line, I want to check if the line contains the date in the YYYY-mm-dd format and if it does, I want to extract the date.

The following code does not work:

```
line = '<option value="29">Soil Temperature (<i>2002-10-17</i>)</option>'
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(line, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

It gives me the error:

```
ValueError: time data '<option value="29">Soil Temperature (<i>2002-10-17</i>)</option>' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

Any way how to easily extract the date?

Comment: is `9999-99-99` a date??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following pattern:

```
\b\d{4}-\d\d?-\d\d?\b
```

---

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import re
>>>
>>> line = '<option value="29">Soil Temperature (<i>2002-10-17</i>)</option>'
>>> dt_list = re.findall(r'\b\d{4}-\d\d?-\d\d?\b', line)
>>> [datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d') for dt in dt_list]
[datetime.datetime(2002, 10, 17, 0, 0)]
```

NOTE: You should escape `\` or use raw string literal as shown in the above example. Otherwise it will interpreted as a escape sequence. Especially `\b` will be interpreted as a BACKSPACE instead of word boundary.

Comment: Does not work if month is only one digit, or if day is only one digit. Change d{2} to d{1,2} in both places to fix.

Comment: @Marichyasana, Thank you for suggestion. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: why is it necessary to use the word boundary \b mark?

Comment: @jirikadlec2, I put word boundary to prevent matching non-date string: for example, `123456-99-888`

Comment: you could rewrite `\d{1,2}` as `\d\d?` that might be easier to understand: `r'\b\d\d\d\d-\d\d?-\d\d?\b'`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, Yes, it's easier to read/understand. I updated the answer accordingly. Thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use a [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) HTML parser in conjunction with [`dateutil`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from dateutil.parser import parse


data = """
<select>
    <option value="29">Soil Temperature (<i>2002-10-17</i>)</option>
    <option value="STO">Soil &amp; Air Temperature (2002-10-17)</option>
</select>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for option in soup('option'):
    print parse(option.text, fuzzy=True)
```

Prints `datetime` objects:

```
2002-10-17 00:00:00
2002-10-17 00:00:00
```

Note that `fuzzy` parsing has a bit surprising behavior - if the date is not found in the string, it would return the current date - see [Trouble in parsing date using dateutil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960614/trouble-in-parsing-date-using-dateutil).