# Parse unformatted dates in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing

I have some text, taken from different websites, that I want to extract dates from. As one can imagine, the dates vary substantially in how they are formatted, and look something like:

```
Posted: 10/01/2014 
Published on August 1st 2014
Last modified on 5th of July 2014
Posted by Dave on 10-01-14
```

What I want to know is if anyone knows of a Python library [or API] which would help with this - (other than e.g. regex, which will be my fallback). I could probably relatively easily remove the "posed on" parts, but getting the other stuff consistent does not look easy.

Comment: `dateutil` has a [parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html) that is pretty forgiving with regards to what date formats you throw at it. That would be my first choice for something like this.

Comment: @LukasGraf - thanks, this worked well - I have posed my code as an answer using this (ran into a couple of problems on what it defaulted to when it ran into missing data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My solution using dateutil**

Following Lukas's suggestion, I used the dateutil package (seemed far more flexible than Arrow), using the Fuzzy entry, which basically ignores things which are not dates.

**Caution on Fuzzy parsing using dateutil**

The main thing to note with this is that as noted in the thread [Trouble in parsing date using dateutil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960614/trouble-in-parsing-date-using-dateutil) if it is unable to parse a day/month/year it takes a default value (which is the current day, unless specified), and as far as i can tell there is no flag reported to indicate that it took the default.

This would result in "random text" returning today's date of 2015-4-16 which could have caused problems.

**Solution**

Since I really want to know when it fails, rather than fill in the date with a default value, I ended up running twice, and then seeing if it took the default on both instances - if not, then I assumed parsing correctly.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

def extract_date(text):

    date = {}
    date_1 = parse(text, fuzzy=True, default=datetime(2001, 01, 01))
    date_2 = parse(text, fuzzy=True, default=datetime(2002, 02, 02))

    if date_1.day == 1 and date_2.day ==2:
        date["day"] = "XX"
    else:
        date["day"] = date_1.day

    if date_1.month == 1 and date_2.month ==2:
        date["month"] = "XX"
    else:
        date["month"] = date_1.month    

    if date_1.year == 2001 and date_2.year ==2002:
        date["year"] = "XXXX"
    else:
        date["year"] = date_1.year  

    return(date)

print extract_date("Posted: by dave August 1st")
```

Obviously this is a bit of a botch (so if anyone has a more elegant solution -please share), but this correctly parsed the four examples i had above [where it assumed US format for the date 10/01/2014 rather than UK format], and resulted in XX being returned appropriately when missing data entered.

Comment: Although it works, `fuzzy="TRUE"` is a bit misleading, why not just `fuzzy=True` ?

Comment: @LiviuChircu - no reason... except that i wrote this when was just learning how to code - updated as you suggested to be cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Arrow](http://arrow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library:

```
arrow.get('2013-05-05 12:30:45', ['MM/DD/YYYY', 'MM-DD-YYYY'])
```

Two arguments, first a str to parse and second a list of formats to try.